# How do we prevent user input of negative numbers?

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

I have a number input field.

How do I prevent the users from entering negative values?

Is there a property I can set on the property inspector?

Answer (score 1):

No as far as I know, but you can use validators, Go to the Component Palete > Operations and find the one that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADFBc as your backend you can create `business rules` on the attribute EntityObject.

Open an EntityObject ---> Left you will find `BusinessRules` ---> Choose your attribute and click on plus icon to the top right and you can create a validation